# Change done on one element of the list is affected to all elements of the list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have to display a list of users and on click of a button I want to display a text inside the button. UserHeader is a component that I import from my list of records (PostList). What I realize is that the action gets affected on all the list element once I click the button and I think this is because the reducer's state array gets filled with the record and everytime I display UserHeader it displays the text inside the button. I want to display the text only on the list element I am already dealing with, not the entire list. Please help me how can I do this with redux. I am refering to the selectPost() function onClick of the button on UserHeader

```
// reducers.js

export const Reducer_posts = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'FETCH_POSTS':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export const Reducer_users = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const Reducer_select = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'SELECT_POST':
      return action.payload;

    case 'DELETE_SELECT':
      return null;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};


//UserHeader.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser, selectPost, deleteSelect } from '../actions';

class UserHeader extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.userId);
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props.select)
    if(!this.props.user) {
      return <div> Loading... </div>
    }

      return <button onClick={this.props.selectPost} className="header"> {this.props.select} </button>


  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    user: state.users.find(user => user.id === ownProps.userId),
    select: state.select
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUser, selectPost, deleteSelect })(UserHeader);


//PostList.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts, selectPost } from '../actions';
import UserHeader from './UserHeader'

class PostList extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  renderList() {
    return this.props.posts.map(post => {
      return (

        <div className = "item" key={post.id}>
          <i className="large middle aligned icon user" />
            <div className="content">
              <div className = "description">
                <h2> {post.title} </h2>
                <p> {post.body} </p>
              </div>

              <UserHeader userId = {post.userId}/>
            </div>
        </div>

      )
    })
  }

  render(){
    return <div className = "ui relaxed divided list"> {this.renderList()} </div>;
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { posts: state.posts, select: state.select };
};

export default connect( mapStateToProps, { fetchPosts, selectPost })(PostList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store on the state elements with an id, in this way you can manage it as you like. 
Example

```
// Let's imagine that this is your initial state. State here is an object of an x 
// object that contains n-object that represents your button.
//
const state = {
    myButtons: [
        {
            id: "unique_id",
            .
            .
        },
        {...}
    ],
    selectedBtn: -1,
}
```

In this scenario you can easily get the button you want passing the id through the action and so the reducer would be something like:

```
export const Reducer_posts = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'FETCH_POSTS':
      const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.myButtons.concat(action.payload)
      return Object.assign({}, newState)
    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export const Reducer_select = (state=[], action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'SELECT_POST': // I think this is fired on click on a button 
      const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.selectedBtn = action.payload.btnId;
      return Object.assign({}, newState);
    case 'DELETE_SELECT': // when you have to delete a button
      const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
      newState.myButtons = 
      newState.myButtons.filter((el) => el.id !== action.payload.id)
      return Object.assign({}, newState);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now the same if you have to change the text with a structure like this, you can easily access to this array using filter and getting the button you want. On your code snippet when your code arrived to the reducer it just returned action.payload, and this is actually wrong, because one of the principle of redux says that the state should be immutable. I learned redux from [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) and I know that can be really difficult at the beginning